# time series with plotly.js fails, w/ fiddle

Tags: javascript, plot, plotly

I'm new working with plotly.js and cannot figure time series plots. If I plot 4 or 5 dates with simple data points the plot works as expected. However, whenever I use more dates, even say 35 dates, it seems plotly can't handle it? That seems ridiculous so I'm sure doing something wrong but look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xcuruwr/2/) and then this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qL5431r5/2/).

```
var x = [ "2016-10-10 12:00:03", "2016-10-11 12:00:03", "2016-10-12 12:00:03"];
var y = [-6, -7, -7];

console.log("x: ", x)
console.log("y: ", y)

var trace1 = {
  x: x,
  y: y,
  type: 'scatter'
};


var data = [ trace1 ];

var layout = {
  title:'Line and Scatter Plot'
};

Plotly.newPlot('plotly', data, layout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Plotly works great with lots of dates, see the attached snippet.

In your fiddle you have a date `2016-10-10 12:30:03` which is followed by a date `2016-10-10 1:00:03` which precedes the first one. This might cause the weird output.

If you work with dates, use [Date objects](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), they will save you a lot of headache when converting different time formats.

```js
var startTime = new Date();
var dataPoints = 100;
var i = 0;
var y1 = 0;
var x = [];
var y = [];

for (i = 0; i < dataPoints; i += 1) {
    startTime.setTime(startTime.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    x.push(startTime.toDateString());
}

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i += 1) {
    y1 += Math.random();
    y.push(y1)

}

var data = [{
  x: x,
  y: y,
  type: 'scatter',
}];

var layout = {
  title:'Lots of dates'
};

Plotly.newPlot('plotly', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div class="graph js-plotly-plot" style="height: 70vh; width:100%" id="plotly">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there are two things going on here:

1. I have learned the hard way that it's best to use datetimes with plotly. I think it stems from the underlying d3, but not sure.
2. Your dates are out of order. You can't just sort the dates, or they will be jumbled relative to your y values. I created an array of objects with `date` and `value` fields, and then sorted on `.date`.

https://jsfiddle.net/qL5431r5/7/

Comment: I actually figured this one out. I used moment.js and added 'am' and 'pm' to the time strings and plotly.js was able to figure it out. Thanks @abalter

Comment: Glad you found a solution.